# Can a sleeping Perl program be killed using kill(SIGKILL, $$)?

Tags: perl, process, kill

I am running a Perl program, there is a module in the program which is triggered by an external process to kill all the child processes and terminate its execution.
This works fine.

But, when a certain function say `xyz()` is executing there is a `sleep(60)` statement on a condition.

Right now the function is executed repeatedly as it is waiting for some value.

When I trigger the kill process as mentioned above the process does not take place.

Does anybody have a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Question is a bit confusing. Are you trying to kill parent process or child process? after forking the two processes have their own address space and are not dependent to each other unless you are using some IPC. Please REPHRASE YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Why is this tagged "proc"? Is it one of the meanings listed in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107791/how-should-the-proc-tag-be-split-up

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you are trying to kill a process from within itself (your `$$` in question subject) when it's sleeping.

If you are killing from a DIFFERENT process, then it will have its own $$. You need to find out the PID of the original process to kill first (by trolling process list or by somehow communicating it from the original process).

Killing a sleeping process works very well

```
$ ( date ; perl5.8 -e 'sleep(100);' ; date ) &

   Wed Sep 14 09:48:29 EDT 2011

$ kill -KILL 8897

   Wed Sep 14 09:48:54 EDT 2011
```

This also works with other "killish" signals ('INT', 'ABRT', 'QUIT', 'TERM')

---

UPDATE: Upon re-reading, may be the issue you meant was that "triggered by an external process" part doesn't happen. If that's the case, you need to:

- Set up a CATCHABLE signal handler in your process before going to sleep (`$SIG{'INT'}`) - SIGKILL can not be caught by a handler.
- Send SIGINT from said "external process"
- Do all the needed cleanup once sleep() is interrupted by SIGINT from SIGINT handler.